# Error with random in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, random

i have error running this following code in python:

```
from random import randint

code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint (1,9), randint(1,9))
guess = raw_input(">")
guesses = 0

while guess != code and guesses < 10:
   print "wrong"
   guesses += 1
   guess = raw_input(">")
```

when i run it in windowpowershell i got this error"ImportError: cannot import name random". i tried to reinstall python but it still not working.  Can someone guide me through this? thank you!

Comment: do you have a file or folder named random in the same directory?

Comment: @Erotemic yes, i found a several files named random ( random.pyc, random.py; test_random.py; test_random_things.py,...) in the python27 directory in  C: drive (im using Window 10)

Answer (score 0):

this is not a bug with the code. I tried running the code with python 2.7 and it runs fine. The only reason you would get this error is if, in C:>Python27>lib, there is no random.py and random. You commented that you found those files in the python27 folder, make sure that they are inside the lib folder inside of python27. Also make sure that your path for python (in `edit environment variables for your account` on windows 10) is the new one since you said you reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another file with the same name `random` as the default module you are trying to import, Python27 will try to import that first. This can cause all sorts of issues. Try using Python3 or rename `random.py` to something else. Also, you should not be creating new files in `C:\Python27`, create a new file `C:\Test\test.py` like so.